How can I scale proportionally by width, height or Z (and ideally by specific edge)
Without getting out a calculator how can I scale up a mesh so that one side is a given length.
Lets say my imported mesh has a width,length,height of 2.31, 5.1, 4.23
I want the width to be 61, I do not want to do is divide 61 by 2.31 then deal with some irrational number.
I want to open a text box enter "61" and be done with it.
Also ideally I'd like to base this not off the width but off a specific edge.
I believe that this is not currently possible? Am I correct about that? So can I create an add-on can someone point me in that direction if indeed it is not possible?

in Object mode type the width in the N panel > Item > Dimensions then apply the scale? In Edit mode you can use the Edit: Mesh Tools and in the N panel > Edit > Mesh Tools > Edge Tools > Set Edge Length but it's for an edge, not an edge loop

In object mode, press N to see the properties of your object.
In the properties panel, go to the "item" tab.
There you will see the dimensions of your object, and if the axes are aligned, you can type new dimensions there (it will also change the scale)
After putting the desired dimensions, apply scale (Ctrl+a) to transfer the changes to the original mesh.


Alternatively, you can create a helper cube, size 1,1,1. And scale it with the desired values (since its sides are 1, no calculations involved), then you use the snapping tools to move/scale/rotate the rest of your mesh snapping to the vertices of this cube.
B during grab to activate a snapping option where you select the base point and the target point. (Snapping options at the top of the screen must be "increment" or "vertex" for this to work well)
The advantage of the helper cube is that you can position it in different places.
You could also simply try to extrude, axis, number if creating new features.
